# Фризы WebView - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, dart

Всем привет. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, при скролле вниз или вверх, виджет WebView фризит (по крайней мере на Android)? Как можно решить эту проблему?
P.S. Использую [эту](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) библиотеку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как проблема была только на Android, нужно было прописать этот код из документации к данному пакету:

```html
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }
```